# What is the most efficient way to add elements with names containing an incrementing index in an object?

Tags: javascript

For the sake of simplicity, lets say I want to create an object with keys that are just numbers in ascending order, and whenever I add a new key-value pair, the key should be a number one more than the previous number. So basically something like:

```
let MyObject = {
     1: 'String',
     2: 'String',
     3: 'String'
}
```

Now, to add the next element, I'd just do `MyObject.4 = 'String'`
but how do I get the `4`?
I can't do something like `MyObject.(MyObject.keys().length + 1)` obviously.
Or can I?

If I can't, the only solution I see is to have lots of if statements like:

```
let nextElementIndex = MyObject.keys().length + 1;

if(nextElementIndex == 4) MyObject.4 = 'String'
else if(nextElementIndex == 5) MyObject.5 = 'String
.
.
.
```

Is there a way I can do something like `MyObject.nextElementIndex = 'String'` and it will append it as `4: 'String'` instead of `nextElementIndex: 'String'`

Comment: An array would pretty much do that work for you by maintaining the `.length` value automatically.

Comment: use `[]`  when you want to use variable to access or insert key

Comment: True, and I would do exactly that if I could, but since I can't... yeah.

Comment: weird you are treating an object like an array. I love reinventing the wheel. You need to use bracket notation, too lazy to find the dupe. `var foo = []; foo.push('bar1'); foo.push('bar2'); foo.push('bar3');` no need to worry about the index...

Comment: @Code Maniac, funny, I tried that but doesn't work. :(

Comment: @vSpecky post the code you tried and error as well to help you further

Answer (score 1):

While it seems counter intuitive to use an object rather than a list, I would simply keep track of the greatest number and then increment.

```js
let MyObject = {

  length: 3,
  1: 'String',
  2: 'String',
  3: 'String'
}

MyObject[MyObject.length+1] = 'String';
MyObject.length++;
```

Comment: Ohh, I thought there existed something like `MyObject[MyObject.length+1]` and I tried it but I wrote it as `MyObject.[MyObject.length+1]` (notice the period). I stand corrected xD

Answer (score 0):

Use an array that manages the length for you.

```
let MyObject = [{num: 'String'}, {num: 'String2'}]

for (var i = 0; i < MyObject.length; i++) {
    console.log(MyObject[i].num); // String, String2
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) and get next key from `obj.size + 1`

```js
// initialize up to 4
const obj = new Map(Array.from({length:4},(_,i) => [i+1, `Item #${i+1}`]));

// get next key
const next = obj.size + 1;
console.log(`Next = ${next}`);// 5
// set next value
obj.set(next, `Item #${next}`);

console.log(Object.fromEntries(obj))
```

As mentioned elsewhere an array might seem more practical